# Singular Value Decomposition, distance from a matrix to the orthogonal projection of a singular vectors onto the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numeric, svd

Here, A matrix is a set of 1000 images of a single digit, each image having resolution of 28x28. $P_{W_d}(A)$ is the orthogonal projection of a dictionary W onto A. Here $W_d$ is an array consisting of the first d vectors in the unitary matrix calculated using the SVD method. The graph shows the distance $||A-P_{W_d}(A)||^2$ as a function of d.

The graph of the corresponding singular values of A, has exact same shape as the given graph, with only difference being the scale of the y axis. The singular values represent the importance for the reconstruction of an image, so I expected the distance graph to go down pretty quickly for the first values but not so much later. Like having the singular values increase the negative slope of the distance. But this doesn't seem to be the case here. Why would the distance decrease so much when the more redundant singular vectors become taken into consideration? When I reconstructed the image using only the first 126 singular vectors, it looked pretty much the same, as expected. I made the graph using python code.

edit: idk why latex didn't format sorry

Comment: Maybe better to ask on [ai.se](https://ai.stackexchange.com/?tags=computer-vision) or [dsp.se](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision). More math/cv experts there. Or even [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you post the Python code? With some dummy data if your data is private, or upload the data to Gist Github or Dropbox or whatever?